# Why is my static array[] of my classes failing

Tags: c++, arrays, static

I can certainly solve this half a dozen ways but I am curious why what I have coded is not working. (VS 2010 Pro C++)

I have a small class

```
class Protocol_element
{
public:
    const char *Argument;
    int EnumID;
    int TrueEnum;
    int FalseEnum;
    bool IsEnabled;
    ...
```

It has an explicit ctor:

```
    Protocol_element(const char * arg, int id, int tru, int fals, bool isEnab)
    {
        Argument = arg;
        EnumID = id;
        TrueEnum = tru;
        FalseEnum = fals;
        IsEnabled = isEnab;
    {
```

Then I have an array of addresses of these class elements that is declared static

```
Protocol_element *Parms::Protocol[] = {
    &Protocol_element("SSLV2", GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2_OFF, true),
    &Protocol_element("SSLV3", GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3_OFF, true),
    &Protocol_element("TLSV1", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_OFF, true),
    &Protocol_element("TLSV1.1", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1_OFF, false),
    &Protocol_element("TLSV1.2", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2_OFF, false),
    &Protocol_element("TLSV1.3", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3_OFF, false),
    nullptr
};
```

I can trace with the debugger through the constructors. I can see my whole array get built just as I would expect. But if I breakpoint on int main() the array now is uninitialized storage.

Why? Why did my array "disappear"?

Comment: You are storing addresses of temporaries that are destroyed immediatly.

Comment: This should not [even compile](https://godbolt.org/z/dxYbf9W1E).

Comment: VS 2010 predates c++11

Comment: @drescherjm this is illegal in any standard. OTOH VS 2010 is incompatible with any standard.

Comment: I old versions of  Visual Studio allowed some use of & to compile that is not standard.

Comment: Not only is VS 2010 predate the C++11 standard, a lot of the C++11 you do find in that compiler either works partially, or is totally bugged.  At the very least, VS 2015 with Update 3 can give you C++11 capabilities.  Of course, the latest compiler is always better to use, but if you want C++11, the furthest you can go back with the Visual Studio suite is VS 2015 (Update 3).  And no, VS 2013 doesn't do it either -- it has to be VS 2015 or beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks. I was not sure, but when it compiled, I expected that it might work. As I said, I can think of a dozen ways to solve the problem, and what I have done now, and works, is

```
Protocol_element Parms::Protocol[] = {
    { "SSLV2", GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2_OFF, true },
    { "SSLV3", GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3_OFF, true },
    { "TLSV1", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_OFF, true },           // TODO: Document
    { "TLSV1.1", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1_OFF, false },
    { "TLSV1.2", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2_OFF, false },
    { "TLSV1.3", GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3_ON, GSK_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_3_OFF, false },
    nullptr
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is invalid. The address-of operator requires an lvalue.

You are however using a non-standard language extension of a very buggy and outdated compiler. This extension prevents the compiler from yelling at you and refusing to compile the program like the standard (any year) requires. Unfortunately it does not cause the compiler to emit meaningful code. So garbage in, garbage out.

You should upgrade to the latest version of MSVC and use the latest standard (the `/std:c++latest` flag), or at the very least disable the non-standard extensions with the `/Za` flag. I cannot guarantee it will help specifically with VS 2010 though, but it does help with modern versions of MSVC.